# IBM Blockchain Platform: Error Creating Smart Contract

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, smartcontracts, ibm-blockchain

Attempting to create a `Smart Contract` on the IBM Blockchain Platform.

I have reviewed and updated all the necessary packages and prerequisites.

[image: Attached here is the error]

Comment: do you have npm installed and added to environment?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I do.  Just for sake of confirmation, I just re-installed with:  sudo npm install -g npm.  Continue to get the same error.

Comment: What version of Node are you running?

Comment: Hello, I've literally given up :(   My current version of node is: v8.16.0  But I also tried with version: 6.  Continue to get the same error.  I'm attempting to learn Hyperledger.

Comment: Can you provide some more details about your operating environment. What OS are you using and what version ? what version of the extension are you using, I am assuming 1.0.4 as this seems to be a common problem with that release. You could try using a different version of the extension. If you right click on the IBM Blockchain Platform Extension in the extensions tab you can try installing an older version, for example 1.0.3. Note that you should have either node 8 or node 10 installed. Node 6 will not work.